# Is findOne() in mongoDB deprecated

Tags: mongodb, deprecation

Is `findOne()` in **MongoDB** deprecated? I am asking this because when I use `findOne()` in *WebStorm* the IDE puts a line through `findOne()` and gives a message saying `findOne()` is deprecated and to find substitute.

I looked in the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) to try and find an answer but it did not mention anything about `findOne()` being deprecated.

If `findOne()` is deprecated what would be the best alternative to this method?

If it is not deprecated does anyone know why WebStorm gives this warning?

Any help with this is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `findOne()` is only deprecated in the Javascript driver.

- [Its fine in the Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)
- [Its fine in the C++ API](http://api.mongodb.com/cxx11/current/classmongocxx_1_1collection.html#a7bc5c6087f55bf9a26b11f85c5ffe2c4)
- [Its fine in the C# API](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection_FindOneAs.htm)
- [Its fine in the Java API](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findOne--)
- [Its fine in the Perl API](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::Collection#find_one)

Worse, MongoDB node driver uses `findOne` internally extensively. The change was made last year, as part of a [series of commits carrying the helpful message "clean up docs"](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/commit/ef73263d97bd784ac6f83920f55bd1e378ff0c6e).

I have no idea why the maintainer added the deprecation warning, so I've created a bug report to remove it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-723

Answer (score 5):

Just got [an answer from the maintainer of the `nodejs` driver](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-890), deprecation has been removed!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What do you know, peer pressure works! Normally I'd recommend against opening known duplicate tickets (even if its for a different version), but this one got the job done so I can't complain much ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem...it took a while to find, but the deprecation is [documented in the native driver for Node](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOne):

> use find().limit(1).next(function(err, doc){})

This is for the 2.1.20 version of mongodb.

Comment: So does this mean that `findOne()` is only deprecated when using MongoDB's node package?

Comment: so in order to do the same thing as `findOne()` would I just do 

 `find({_id: id}).limit(1).each(function (error, dbValueIWantInJson) {  
                console.log(dbValueIWantInJson);
        });`

 I am not sure what the best way to use `find().limit(1).next(function(err, doc){})` ?

Comment: @Tim I did something similar to: `collection.find({ _id: id }).limit(1).next(function(findErr, results) {  ...do stuff with results... }`